# How do I take screenshots and video in Desert Golfing?

Tags: pc, desert-golfing

While playing Desert Golfing, there is a clear need to capture more of these great moments:

[image: desert golfing oops]

Some screen captures and have already appeared in the Desert Golfing program directory. This is great! Clearly, these were created while I was playing, but I was unaware of making them. Try as I might, I can't figure out the keyboard/mouse combo for new screenshots.

Is there a keyboard/mouse command to get more of these? Or are they created automatically?

[image: desert golfing program directory]

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? If you are, then use Windows + Alt + PrtScn to capture screenshots while playing games. Alternatively, you can bring up the Game Bar by pressing Windows + G and then click the screenshot button on it. The game bar also gives you options to capture videos of your games. You can find other methods for taking screenshots, detailed here: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-take-screenshots-windows-8-81-using-built-tools

Comment: The above screenshots were taken on a Windows 7 PC. I understand (generally) how to take screen captures. This question is essentially: what caused Desert Golfing to create "hole0.gif / hole7.gif / hole13.gif / etc." in the app's working directory? Was is a keystroke I accidentally hit? Did something happen in-game to trigger this?